# How to change javascript for loop criteria? Newbie question

Tags: javascript, jquery

Javascript newbie here, just trying to tweak this bit of code. It checks for all HTML elements with a title attribute and adds the class 'tooltipParent'.

I'd like it to only add the class to elements with a title attribute AND the class 'tooltip'. I think I need to add something to the *for* loop to check for this extra class?

```
// loop through all objects with a title attribute
var titles=$('[title]');

// use an efficient for loop as there may be a lot to cycle through
for(var i=titles.length-1;i>-1;i--){

   // titled object must be position:relative
   $(titles[i]).addClass('tooltipParent');

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is not just javascript, but jQuery, its nice to say it as google visitors can understand what is it about. The lonesomeday's answer is right btw

Comment: @Tomalak: I commented one minute before you posted your answer

Comment: @Jonathan Or, in fact, two minutes after. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the class requirement into your original selector:

```
$('*.tooltip[title]').addClass('tooltipParent');
```

---

This means

- select all elements (`*`)
- with the class "tooltip" (`.tooltip`)
- and a title attribute set (`[title]`)
- and add the class `tooltipParent`

Answer (score 1):

You can extend your jQuery selector on the first line to select the proper elements. Look at [the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for help. It's probably something like `var titles = $('.tooltip[title]')`.

Comment: Also, I don't see why you're using "an efficient for loop". jQuery can iterate over collections itself. Just apply the property to the entire resultset, as _lonesomeday_ showed you in his answer.